# Mule 4 Database Insert into Oracle Table with Date field issues

Tags: oracle, date, mule, mulesoft, mule4

Am using Mule 4 ( runtime 4.3 ) running in anypoint studio ( 7.15.0 )

Am trying to do a simple database insert ( Database is Oracle )

Here is the relevant code for insert :

```
    <db:insert doc:name="Insert emp record"  config-ref="Emp_Database_Config" >
                <db:sql ><![CDATA[ insert into emp ( emp_id, emp_name, start_date ) values ( :empId, :empName , TO_DATE(:startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) ]]></db:sql>
                <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    'empId' : vars.empId,
    'empName' : vars.empName,
    'startDate' : '3000-01-01'  
}]]]></db:input-parameters>
            
</db:insert>
```

Here `start_date` is a `Date` field in `emp` table.
Am trying to do a date insert using following code:

```
TO_DATE('3000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

However it fails at runtime with following error:

> ERROR 2023-12-02 20:10:45,224 [[MuleRuntime].uber.08:
> [emp-sys-v1_to_checkin].process-emp-flow.BLOCKING @7d642671]
> org.mule.db.commons.shaded.internal.domain.executor.AbstractExecutor:
> An SQLException exception has occurred. java.sql.SQLException: An
> SQLException was provoked by the following failure:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be
> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

Google search provided this mulesoft help article:
https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Database-Connector-Timestamp-format-must-be-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss-fffffffff-Oracle-DB-Mule-4

Based on this tried appending  as :

```
'startDate' : '3000-01-01'  ++ " 00:00:00.00000"
```

However then started getting this error:

> 'ORA-01858  a non-numeric character was located where a digit was
> expected'

**Database Connector - Mule 4 1.14.6**

Database table is in `Oracle` and in the table 'emp' , the field 'start_date' is a `Date` field

If I do a direct database insert via `sql plus` I can do an insert without issues using :

```
TO_DATE('3000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Not sure why such a simple activity is failing due to Date issues ....

Edit1:
am aware that Date does hold time

Edit2:
also tried to send data as `application/java` and still encountering this issue

Answer (score 1):

Try to match the query format with the argument format:

```
TO_DATE(:date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

```
'startDate' : '3000-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same error during inserting date field in oracle db.

> An SQLException was provoked by the following failure:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be
> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]

@aled answer will definitely will work for you but the below format worked for me. See if it helps for you

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
'startDate' : ("'" ++ (|3000-01-01| as Date{format: "yyyy-MM-dd"} as String{format: "dd-MMM-yyyy"}}) ++ "'")
```

```
'startDate' : '01-Jan-3000'
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, for a fixed date replace `"3000-01-01" as Date{format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}` by a Date constant `|3000-01-01|` to avoid an unneeded conversion. If the value is a dynamic string then the conversion to Date is required.